# Android Hierarchical Navigation

Tags: android

I'm trying to get an example or a starting reference on how to develop a drill down structure. The best example I can give is, how Android navigates through it's own folder structure. Here is a screenshot to illustrate my point:

[image]

Some things I would like to point out:

- I will have know knowledge of how deep the structure will run
- Minimum API level 10

Could someone please point me in the right direction.
Many thank in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To those you are wondering how I managed this, I basically call the same activity, just with the parent ID (which will be located within the bundle). This way I can fill the `ListView` with the parent ID provided and let my `BaseAdapter` sort out which UI to display.

I don't know if the was the best way of doing it, but it worked for me.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

IMO, technically there is no limit on the structure depth. But for the sake of design, good user interaction with the app as well as for codes maintenance, I suggest 3 to 5 level deep is enough. If you must go further than that perhaps you should re-design the app.

And you may also use breadcrumb to improve structure visibility.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs.html